# JProgressBar frame is always minimized when started

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

**Situation**: A simple progress bar is to be displayed when a button on a webpage is clicked.

This is the class:

```
public class SwingProgressBarExample extends JPanel {

  JProgressBar pbar;

  static final int MY_MINIMUM = 0;

  static final int MY_MAXIMUM = 100;

  public SwingProgressBarExample() {
    // initialize Progress Bar
    pbar = new JProgressBar();
    pbar.setMinimum(MY_MINIMUM);
    pbar.setMaximum(MY_MAXIMUM);
    // add to JPanel
    add(pbar);
  }

  public void updateBar(int newValue) {
    pbar.setValue(newValue);
  }
}
```

This is how I invoke the class:

```
final SwingProgressBarExample it = new SwingProgressBarExample();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Progress Bar Example");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setContentPane(it);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

**Problem**: The progress bar is always minimized. I want it to show on the center of the screen for the viewer to see.

I've tried `setVisible(true)`, but it doesn't seem to work. The Frame is always minimized when its initialized and started.

Answer (score -1):

The key is to add line number 5 in the code below

```
frame.setSize(200,200);

frame.setVisible(true);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);

//Add This Line
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

frame.setContentPane(it);
```

The line ***frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);*** forces to window to be on top of anything else.